# Accessing UNC paths in SYSTEM context

Tags: windows, windows-domain, unc

I need to access a UNC path from a process which is running as SYSTEM user in a Windows Domain. When running this application under Windows 10 it is working fine but on Windows 7 I get an Access Denied error. If the network path is mapped as a network drive on Windows 7, I can access it but this is not really an option.

The way I want to access the path is exactly the same on both OS versions so I think there might be something configured differently.

I was wondering if there might be an option in Windows to change how the local SYSTEM account is trying to authenticate on network servers. Are there any options in Windows that I should check?

Answer (score 0):

#### Grant access to the source computer's AD object

The SYSTEM identity is both local and unique to each computer. By default it does not have permission to access resources that are not on the local machine.

To grant processes running in the context of the SYSTEM account on Computer A to a resource on Computer B, on Computer B grant access to the AD computer object of Computer A. For example if Computer A is named `SERVER1` on Computer B you would give permissions to the object named `SERVER1$`.

**Note** You can only do this in a domain. Computers not joined to a domain don't have a trust path to each other, and unlike with normal user accounts, there's no way to directly authenticate to a remote computer and specify *only* the credentials of the SYSTEM account.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with permissions on the computer that holds the data I want to access, otherwise it wouldn't have worked with Windows 10 right?

Comment: Not necessarily true. If you read my answer you see that the permissions are granted *per-computer*. So the Windows 10 machine may have permission, but the Windows 7 doesn't. This is what you need to do to grant the permissions for the Win 7 box.

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't thought about that. Both machines are part of a test environment. They're all members of the same groups. Just for testing purposes I granted Anonymous and computername$ the necessary permissions but still got an access denied error.

Comment: Have the default settings for the machines' User Rights Assignments been modified?